# Who is the author "DT in Oakland"?

Tags: authors, john-varley

I asked John Varley about this directly, but he says he forgot.

In his 1986 short "The Unprocessed Word", he cites three other authors whose work in longhand and/or typewriter proves that you don't need a word processor. These are: SK in Maine, SR in Halifax, and DT in Oakland.

SK is Stephen King, SR is Spider Robinson, and neither I nor Varley know who "DT" is. Anyone have a guess?

Comment: Quite a few listed on [isfdb](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=author_lastname&OPERATOR_1=starts_with&TERM_1=t&CONJUNCTION_1=AND&USE_2=author_canonical&OPERATOR_2=starts_with&TERM_2=d&CONJUNCTION_2=AND&USE_3=author_canonical&OPERATOR_3=exact&TERM_3=&ORDERBY=author_lastname&START=0&TYPE=Author)

Comment: Funny that he should mention Stephen King, who was virtually one of the first people ever to use a word processor. Oh well.

Comment: @MrLister I didn't know that. I thought Jerry Pournelle was one of the first people ever to use a word processor. His Wikipedia page says "He is recognized as the first author to have written a published book contribution using a word processor on a personal computer, in 1977."

Comment: Stephen King actually has his own mystic artifact, a particular sheaf of paper which he wrote his first published book with, and which he claims is linked to the successful first book of a few other authors. Word-processor-wise, I associate with the Word Processor  of the Gods, which is fiction.

Comment: JRR "Dave" Tolkien, of course.

Comment: @Danny Sichel It's a stretch but Dylan Thomas is supposed to be famous for using a Parker 51 pen, and I get the feeling he was at Oakland for a while.